# Fill SVG Color while it is a background

Tags: css

I am trying to put an `svg` as background, and then fill it with an color which doesn't work.

```
#header-container { background-color:transparent; background-image: url(http://somewebsite.com/images/wallp.svg); fill: red; }
```

This does not seem to work...
any advide?

Comment: You cannot style SVG images with CSS as you seem to want to do. You **can** style **inline SVG elements** with CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/p5Az4/3/

**HTML**

```
<svg id="header-container" xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" i:viewOrigin="226.9077 360.5469" i:rulerOrigin="0.5 -0.5" i:pageBounds="-0.5 612.5 791.5 0.5" width="303.044" height="72.375" viewBox="0 0 303.044 72.375" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 303.044 72.375" xml:space="preserve">
  <!-- too markup to past here -->
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-container {fill: red;}
```

**Image Result without your style**

[image]

Your example, I am sorry, can't work, because the **[fill property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972257(v=vs.85).aspx)**

> Sets or retrieves a value that indicates the color to paint the
>   interior of the given graphical element.

You can apply them to shapes and text content elements, in accord to [SPEC](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#FillProperties)

Where **[shape](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermShape)** is:

> A graphics element that is defined by some combination of straight
>   lines and curves. Specifically: ‘path’, ‘rect’, ‘circle’, ‘ellipse’,
>   ‘line’, ‘polyline’ and ‘polygon’.

and **[text content element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermTextContentElement)** is:

> A text content element is an SVG element that causes a text string to
>   be rendered onto the canvas. The SVG 1.1 text content elements are the
>   following: ‘altGlyph’, ‘textPath’, ‘text’, ‘tref’ and ‘tspan’

So

> The ‘fill’ property paints the interior of the given graphical
>   element. The area to be painted consists of any areas inside the
>   outline of the shape. To determine the inside of the shape, all
>   subpaths are considered, and the interior is determined according to
>   the rules associated with the current value of the ‘fill-rule’
>   property. The zero-width geometric outline of a shape is included in
>   the area to be painted.
>
> The fill operation fills open subpaths by performing the fill
>   operation as if an additional "closepath" command were added to the
>   path to connect the last point of the subpath with the first point of
>   the subpath. Thus, fill operations apply to both open subpaths within
>   ‘path’ elements (i.e., subpaths without a closepath command) and
>   ‘polyline’ elements.